# Prometheus range duration in Range vector w.r.t. Grafana time interval

Tags: prometheus, grafana, micrometer, promql, spring-micrometer

I am using micrometer with prometheus and grafana for dashbaords.
my prom query is : rate(my_counter[10m])
Now, My current date is 1-Jun-2020  and I select the past dates in time interval of grafana as 1-Feb-2020 to 4-Mar-2020.
In this case, the rate function will use only 10 minutes of data w.r.t. 4-Mar-2020 23:59:59.
Is my understanding correct, if no can someone please explain how does it work?

Comment: Found answer to my question..

A nice video which explains how it works..
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=09bR9kJczKM&t=179s

and this blog
https://utcc.utoronto.ca/~cks/space/blog/sysadmin/PrometheusQuerySteps#:~:text=The%20Prometheus%20expression%20browser's%20graph,anything%20else%20about%20the%20query.

Comment: Consider summarizing in a couple of sentences and posting your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

Prometheus calculates `rate(my_counter[10m])` independently per each point on the graph. If Grafana draws a graph on a time range from `1-Feb-2020` to `4-Mar-2020`, it sends the request to [/api/v1/query_range](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/api/#range-queries) with the corresponding query args: `start=1-Feb-2020`, `end=4-Mar-2020`. The `step` query arg is calculated depending on the horizontal pixel resolution of the graph and the selected time range, so the total number of returned datapoints is proportional to `pixel_width` of the graph. Usually Grafana sets `step` to an interval, which corresponds to around 1000 points per graph. If the lookbehind window specified in square brackets (e.g. `[10m]` in `rate(my_counter[10m])` is smaller than `step` query arg, then some raw samples aren't taken into account when drawing the graph. If the lookbehind window is bigger than `step` query arg, then some raw samples are used multiple times for `rate()` calculations over adjacent points on the graph.

Grafana provides `$__interval` template variable, which equals to `step` value - see [these docs](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/variables/variable-types/global-variables/#__interval) for details. So just use `$__interval` instead of fixed lookbehind window if all the raw samples must be taken into account when building the graph on any time range:

```
rate(my_counter[$__interval])
```

Side note: the `$__interval` in square brackets can be omitted when using `MetricsQL`:  `rate(my_counter)`. See [these docs](https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics/wiki/MetricsQL) for details.

Full disclosure: I'm the author of `MetricsQL` and `VictoriaMetrics` :)

Comment: The link does not work anymore. Attaching updated one: [grafana_interval](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/variables/variable-types/global-variables/#__interval)

Comment: Thanks! Fixed the link.